# what is the purpose of main.yml file in vars folder in ansible role?

Tags: ansible

my task is to copy file in file folder, template in templates folder to remote host ``

template file has nothing just text.

templates/templateexample.txt.j2
=>This is the example template to be transferred.

vars/main.yml

```
---
project_files:
  files:
    - src: "examplefile1.txt"
      dst: "~/examplefile1.txt"
      mode: '0755'
      force: false
  templates:
    - src: "templateexample.txt.j2"
      dst: "~/templateexample.txt"
      mode: '0755'
      force: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**file: `copy-static.yml`**:

```yaml
---
- name: Copy a file
  copy: src=examplefile1.txt dest=/home/user/example.txt
```

**file: `copy-template.yml`**:

```yaml
---
- name: sample template - x
  template:
    src: templateexample.txt.j2
    dest: /home/user/newexample.txt
  with_items: var_x
```

**file: `ngnix.yml`**

```yaml
---
    - name: install nginx
     apt: name=nginx update_cache=yes state=latest
    - name: displaying message
      debug: msg="yayy!! nginx installed"
```

**file: `mainplaybook.yml`**:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  roles:
    - fresco_roles/sample_role
```

**file: `tasks/main.yml`**:

```yaml
---
- include: nginx.yml
- include: copy-static.yml
- include: copy-template.yml
```

**file: `hosts`**:

```ini
[localhost]
localhost
```

**file: `vars/main.yml`**:

```yaml
---
project_files:
  files:
    - src: "examplefile1.txt"
      dst: "~/examplefile1.txt"
      mode: '0755'
      force: false
  templates:
    - src: "templateexample.txt.j2"
      dst: "~/templateexample.txt"
      mode: '0755'
      force: false
var_x:
  - 'variable x'
var_y:
  - 'variable y'
```

Comment: I cannot understand how this answer addresses the question at all.  The question appears to be asking what vars/main.yml is about, and this appears to be an entire playbook without commentary

Comment: it seems good enough, he provide an example

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"What is the purpose of the `main.yml` file in the `vars` folder in the Ansible role?"***

A: Main reason is to customize the role's default variables.

The variables defined in *`role/vars/main.yml`* override all variables defined in roles defaults, inventories, group_vars, host_vars, and all variables defined in the play before the role was included in the play. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

For example, let's create a playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_var: test_var defined in the playbook vars
  roles:
    - role1
```

and let's create a role with empty *`roles/role1/vars/main.yml`* and simple debug task in *`roles/role1/tasks/main.yml`*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role1/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: test_var

shell> cat roles/role1/vars/main.yml 
---
# vars file for role1
```

The play will display the variable defined in the playbooks' vars

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 
  ...
  test_var: test_var defined in the playbook vars
```

Now, define the variable *test_var* in role's *`roles/role1/vars/main.yml`*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role1/vars/main.yml 
---
# vars file for role1
test_var: test_var defined in the role vars
```

The variable defined in the **playbook's vars** was overridden by the variable defined in the **role's vars**

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 
  ...
  test_var: test_var defined in the role vars
```

---

Notes:

- Do not put roles' *vars* into the Ansible Galaxy git. This will preserve local customizations from updates and upgrades.